# Check if element attribute has specific value JS

Tags: javascript

Is there a way in javascript to check if an element has a certain attribute value?
Given this code:

```html
<div class="wrapper">
   <a href=#refresh-cart>view cart</a>
</div>
```

is there a way to be more specific rather than

```js
document.addEventListener('click', e => {
  if (e.target.hasAttribute('href')) {
    //...
  }
})
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the value. Compare it to what you want.

```
if (e.target.getAttribute('href') === "foo")
```